# How to show 12AM and 12PM on x-axis using highcharts library

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a chart with some data, i am showing data on x-axis on the basis of hours in a day with interval of 2 hours.
The code is as fellow:

```
startOnTick: true,
endOnTick: true,
showLastLabel: true,
type: 'datetime',
tickInterval: 3600 * 2000,
min: minDate,
max: maxDate,
dateTimeLabelFormats: {
    hour: '%I %p',
     minute: '%I:%M %p'
}
```

minDate mean start of first day and maxDatemean last time of last day.

now i want to show 12AM and 12PM on the place date because in case of week the date is not readeable.

[image]

Comment: So 12AM / 12PM should be instaed of days? I guess that printscreen is from current chart, so which labels should be replaced with others?

Comment: So 12AM / 12PM should be instaed of days (27. May, 28. May)

Comment: In the dateTimeLabelFormat try to add this line: day: '%I %p',

Comment: @SebastianBochan not working.

Comment: Please replicate your example as live demo on jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 1):

I found this answer:

```
 labels: {
    enabled: true,
    formatter: function (){
              return Highcharts.dateFormat('%I %p',this.value);
    },
}
```